# How to replace regex with digit in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that includes a series of information that identifies a group of people by their current board memberships. It looks like this:

```
company_board <- c("company1", "company2", "company3; company 1", "", "")
nonprofit_board <- c("nonprofit1", "", "nonprofit5; nonprofit2", "", "nonprofit3")
df <- data.frame(company_board, nonprofit_board, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to convert these into simple 1 if there is information in the cell or 0 if there is no data recorded. So for the example I've just given:

```
company_board <- c("1", "1", "1", "0", "0")
nonprofit_board <- c("1", "0", "1", "0", "1")
df <- data.frame(company_board, nonprofit_board, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I know how to use `str_extract` with `[:alnum:]` to get the cells that should be 1 but I can't figure out how to then replace these cells with 1 (and the remainder with 0). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also convert to `matrix` and apply `nchar` directly

```
+(nchar(as.matrix(df)) > 0)
#     company_board nonprofit_board
#[1,]             1               1
#[2,]             1               0
#[3,]             1               1
#[4,]             0               0
#[5,]             0               1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` and test if `nchar` is more than `0`.

```
sapply(df, function(x) +(nchar(x)>0))
#     company_board nonprofit_board
#[1,]             1               1
#[2,]             1               0
#[3,]             1               1
#[4,]             0               0
#[5,]             0               1
```

Or shorter:

```
+(sapply(df, nchar)>0)
```

In case you have `" "` you can add something like `trimws`:

```
sapply(df, function(x) +(nchar(trimws(x))>0))
```

Or using `nzchar` seen already in @ThomasIsCoding's answer.

```
+sapply(df, nzchar)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I'll accept this answer as soon as the system allows me

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to make it is using `nzchar`

```
dfout <- +data.frame(Map(nzchar,df))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  company_board nonprofit_board
1             1               1
2             1               0
3             1               1
4             0               0
5             0               1
```